# parse-server: Cannot upload a file using REST API and GridStoreAdapter

Tags: parse-server

This is my server's configuration:

```
{
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/mydb',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myappid',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'masterkey',
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',
  publicServerURL: 'http://myserverip:1337/parse',
  fileKey: "myfilekey"
}
```

I'm using a custom made service in angular. This is the code I'm using to upload files.

```
ParseService.prototype.uploadFile = function(file) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: this.api.url + "/files/" + file.name,
        headers: _.extend(_.clone(this.headers), {"Content-Type": "image"}),
        data: file
    });
}
```

I also tried to upload a file using parse-dashboard and I get the same response.

When I'm trying to upload a file in my migrated app I get this response:

```
{"code":130,"error":"Could not store file."}
```